# #document showing when trying to run poweshell but no error

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Below part of code is getting following result: "Package Validation Process Started for - 3. PTW_Dashboards.zip....
Package Validation Process Finished for - 3. PTW_Dashboards.zip
Package Import Process Started for - 3. PTW_Dashboards.zip...
Reading the Package data...
#document
Package Import Process Completed for -  3. PTW_Dashboards.zip
Logout Process Started...
Logout Process completed"

```
function ImportPackage([String] $MeridiumToken, [String] $PackageName, [String] $PkgItems, [String] $DNSURL,
    [String] $DBConnStr, [String] $DBTableName, [String] $ReleaseID, [String] $pkgID) {
    
    try {
        Write-Host "Package Import Process Started for - $PackageName..."
        
        $APIIURL = $DNSURL + '/apm/api/v1/core/metadata/import/selecteditems'
    
        # Encode Type
        $EncodeType = "iso-8859-1"
    
        # Dynamic input parameters section
        $FilePath = "$($env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/Subtract-a-thon/Automation/" + $PackageName
        
        # Header
        $IHeaders = @{ 'MeridiumToken' = $MeridiumToken }
    
        # Reading Package
        Write-Host "Reading the Package data..."
        $FileBinary = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FilePath)
    
        $Enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($EncodeType)
        $FileEnc = $Enc.GetString($FileBinary)
    
        $CRLF = "`r`n"
        $Boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
    
        # FileName
        $File_Name = Split-Path $FilePath -leaf
    
        # Request Body
        $IBody = (
            "--$Boundary",
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"file`"; filename=`"$File_Name`"",
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream$CRLF",
            $FileEnc,
            $CRLF,
            "--$Boundary",
            "Content-Type:application/json",
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"items`"$CRLF",
            $PkgItems,
            "--$Boundary--"
        ) -join $CRLF
    
        # Request Content Type
        $IContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`""
        
        # REST Call
        $ImportLog = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $APIIURL -Method Post -Headers $IHeaders -ContentType $IContentType -Body $IBody


        Write-Host $ImportLog
        Write-Host "Package Import Process Completed for - " $PackageName
            }
    catch {
        Write-Host "An error occurred:"
        Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace
        throw $_
    }
}
```

No error is throwing but there is import happening as well

Comment: Your query is not returning any data.  Try simplifying the body of the request and see if data is returned.  Check if Invoke-RestMethod is returning a status of 200 OK or a 400/500 error.

Comment: Tried checking status code but Https Status Code is returning nothing, neither 200 or 400/500

Comment: That usually means the connection never completed.  You only get a status code after a connection completed.   When a connection doesn't complete you should get a timeout error.   You are not getting a timeout.  From status messages you posted I think the server is logging out before sending a response (contains the status) and closing connection.  When connection closes Invoke-Request will continue with null response.

Comment: I was able to get past it